Существует ли plugin под flake8 для контроля литералов с плавающей точкой?
Интересует выдача предупреждений на литералы, которые не имеют точного представления, например 0.1. А, к примеру, литерал: 0.25 - "хороший".
Особенно при работе с пакетами numpy, gmpy2 и др., приходится следить за ошибками вида (пример для Intel/AMD/Power/...):
import numpy as np

good = np.float128('0.3')
fail = np.float128(0.3)
print((good - fail)/np.finfo(fail).eps)

Для расширенной точности Intel/AMD/Motorola получим:
102.5

Для честных IEEE bynary128 бит:
57646075230342349.0

Т.е. и при работе с float литерал 0.3 имеет ошибку 0.5 ULP, но для np.longdouble() это уже больше 100 ULP.

А что у вас за версия Питона и под какую систему? У меня ваш код выдаёт 0.0. Питон же "умный", он и сам знает о проблемных литералах и сам их как-то поправляет где может. На уровне чего это происходит нужно дальше смотреть, но, повторюсь, у меня он разницы между обоими представлениями не видит от слова совсем. Кстати, добавьте в вопрос вывод вашего кода.

может, вам посмотреть в сторону pydantic с его decimal->condecimal -> decimal_places?

@CrazyElf long double разный, на процессорах  ARM (или, скажем, в pycharm для всех процессоров) он совпадает с double (python float), поэтому проблема не видна, да и немного меньше, но всё равно остаётся. Ну а в cpython на Intel/AMD она более заметна.

@strawdog спасибо, там пишут, что его "легко" интегрировать с вашими linter/IDE, но ссылок на таковую интеграцию не заметно. А так вроде бы это проверки времени исполнения, которые данную проблему не решают. Быть может.

@Serge3leo "или, скажем, в pycharm для всех процессоров", "Ну а в cpython на Intel/AMD она более заметна"  - pycharm - это не интерпретатор, это просто IDE. Он запускает код через установленный обычный интерпретатор python, тот же cpython например.

И всё же добавьте, что именно ваш код печатает. Очень странно приводить вроде как проблемный код и не приводить вывод этого кода. Кстати, у меня и с родным float печатает 0.0 и c np.float64 и со всем с чем я пробовал. А np.float128 на моей системе нет. (

"там пишут, что его "легко" интегрировать с вашими linter/IDE, но ссылок на таковую интеграцию не заметно" - потому что не нужно никаких дополнительных "настроек интеграции", IDE сами понимают аннотации. Но это в вашей проблеме не факт что поможет.

Если резюмировать, вам нужны те литералы, которые можно точно представить в двоичном виде (без "периодов" в знаках после запятой). Это по сути те числа, которые можно представить в виде рациональной дроби с 2**n в знаменателе (0.25 -> 25/100 -> 1/4). Можно как-то от этого определения отталкиваться.

@insolor, pycharm использует/ставит numpy без поддержки расширенной точности на всех  процессорах. Но если дать своё, внешнее, виртуальное или conda окружение, то всё как обычно. А аннотации типов, это, наверное, немного про другое, тип правильный, просто литерал (константа) не имеет точного представления в данном типе.

Ошибка воспроизводится (Linux 64, Intel, Python 3.10, NumPy 1.22.4). Математика понятна, недавно было несколько вопросов на смежные темы. Видео, где пишется плагин, анализирующий AST, есть. Могу помочь, поучаствовать, написать сам.

@insolor, немного не так, разыскиваются средства анализа кода python (лучше plugin для flake8), которые могут находить таковые константы в коде и выдавать отчёт о замеченном.

@insolor, помимо степени двойки в знаменателе, нужно чтобы мантисса занимала не более 53 бит (или меньше при денормализации), и чтобы порядок не приводил к нулю или бесконечности.

@StanislavVolodarskiy сначала надо поискать. Математика, да, понятна. С логикой сложнее, надо же, что бы было по-меньше ложно-положительной диагностики, да и вообще было удобно писать тот же 0.1 или 3.1415, там где он действительно нужен или реально имеется виду число π для военного времени.

@Serge3leo, чтобы понять к каким труностям приведёт такой плагин, его сперва надо написать. В анализ попадёт AST выражения, как я понимаю. Случаи вроде np.float128(0.3) в таком случае обрабатываются не сложно. Но, повторюсь, плагин уже можно писать.

@StanislavVolodarskiy А вот на Windows 64, Intel, Python 3.10.12, Numpy 1.26.1 показывает 0.0, интересно, куда в итоге то концы проблемы идут.

@CrazyElf, на моей системе np.float128 отображается в long double 80bit. На вашей, видимо, double и long double совпадают. Определяет это компилятор.

@CrazyElf На Intel/AMD NumPy, без относительно системы, можно собрать, как с поддержкой расширенной точности, так и без поддержки (вариант double == long double). Conda/conda-forge собирают с поддержкой, а pycharm, по умолчанию, имеет свой репозиторий пакетов, и там без поддержки. Наверное, есть ещё другие варианты, к примеру, фокусы с автоопределением компиляторов при при локальной сборке NumPy в случае pip установки.

Наличие/отсутствие float128 на саму задачу не влияет. Питон молча округляет вещественные литералы. Требуется отловить такие случаи и показать их пользователю.
